# java regex to strip root element in xpath string

Tags: java, regex, groovy

What's the easiest way to strip the root element from an xpath string where anything matching `/\w/`, as long as the path starts with that pattern, like this:

`/root/foo/bar/sushi` becomes `foo/bar/sushi`

`/my/t/fine/path` becomes `t/fine/path`

I got this working:

```
String path = '/root/foo/bar/sushi'
path.replaceFirst('\\/(.*?)\\/', '')
```

but if `path='root/foo/bar/sushi'`, I don't want anything changed, since that doesn't start with `/`, but it still strips out the first occurrence of `/element/`, resulting in `rootbar/sushi`. I understand why, just having trouble validating the start pattern.

Comment: FYI added token-by-token explanation and a second option. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `^` anchor to specify that we are looking for `/root/` at the beginning of the string. At the simplest, this regex will do it:

```
^/[^/]*/
```

In Java code, this can look like:

```
String replaced = your_original_string.replaceAll("^/[^/]*/", "");
```

This works if you know that what you are looking at is a path in the first place.

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
/                        # '/'
[^/]*                    # any character except: '/' (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
/                        # '/'
```

**Option 2: validate at the same time**

On the other hand, if you are not sure that the string is a path, then this regex is not adequate because it will accept any character after the `/root/`

In that case, you can specify your characters, for instance with

```
^/[^/]*/([\w-/]+)
```

for digits, letters, underscores and hyphens. This validation can be further refined to ensure that the characters occur in the right order.

For this regex, you would replace with:

```
String replaced = your_original_string.replaceAll("^/[^/]*/([\\w-/]+)", "$1");
```

Comment: my bad, the root element can be anything enclosed in `/` and `/`, not just the literal `/root/`

Comment: @raffian Okay, please see update. I'll also post a slightly expanded regex in a minute, but if you know that what you are looking at is a path, it's what you need.

Comment: Option 1 is working, thank you, but what's the deal with option 2? it appears to be doing the same as option 1; it's validating the xpath path? (thanks for the explanation too! :-))

Comment: @raffian Thanks for letting me know that it works. :) option 2 is for validating that the string is a valid path at the same time, for instance it will not work on `/root/ or beetroots?...` If you already know that the string is a path, use option 1.